# Extend ObjectModel using string as ID type

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am using Prestashop 1.7.1.2.
I want to create a class that extends ObjectModel but I need to have a primary Id type of string, not an integer.
How can I achieve that , do I have to override the ORM's load() function?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Of course, how did I forgot! I kept the prestashop's product id as the primary key and xref id as an indexed column. When I need to instantiate using xref Id, I run a direct Db query and then I hydrate the object. This can also be improved to choose between xref id or primary id instantiation.

```
class ProductXrefMap extends ObjectModel {
    public $id_xref; //guid from mssql
    public $date;    
    public $force_id = true;
    public static $definition = array(
        'table' => 'product_xref_table',
        'primary' => 'id_product', //prestashop's product id
        'fields' => array(
            'id_xref' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isString', 'required' => true, 'size' => 64),
            'date' => array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate', 'required' => true)
        )
    );
    public function __construct ($id_xref=null)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        if ($id_xref) 
        {
            $sql_select = "SELECT * FROM " . _DB_PREFIX_ . "product_xref_table WHERE id_xref = '" . $id_xref . "'";
            if ($row = Db::getInstance()->getRow( $sql_select ) )
                $this->hydrate($row);
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So far nobody has helped you. I will try to think together with you. Im not an expert in prestashop developing. But hope to get you further.

This is how I made my ObjectModel. Is your primary ID configured as string in your phpmyadmin table???

```
/**
 * @see ObjectModel::$properties
 */
public $id_product;
public $serial_key;

/**
 * @see ObjectModel::$definition
 */

public static $definition = array(
    'table' => 'avanto_keys',
    'primary' => 'id_avanto_keys',
    'multilang' => FALSE,
    'fields' => array(
        'id_product' =>           array('type' => self::TYPE_ID),
        'serial_key' =>           array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Thank you for even trying. Yes, it is configured as varchar(64) (because its a cross reference field with a Guid from an mssql database). So when I create a new instance of that class , the ID field is converted/parsed to an Int (in that case , id_avanto_keys). I used a workaround and I think its working.

Comment: Hi. Can you share the solution with us? Maybe we will need it one day. Thanks!